# ¿Cómo paso el valor de una variable o constante de una función a una clase que están en el mismo componente? R

Tags: funciones, react-native, clase, expo

tengo un problema, tengo una función llamada Student, y una Clase llamada Parent, dentro de la función Student hay una variable llamada "student" que tiene valores que necesito leer en la clase Parent para enviarlos a otro componente usando AsyncStorage. El problema es que no se si es posible leer los datos de esta variable o cual es la forma correcta de acceder a ella desde la clase. Agradecería cualquier ayuda. Pd: Están en el mismo componente.

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Modal, Pressable, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import style from "../Style/Student.style";

class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            father: [],
            studentData: '',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.dataReader();
        this.setData();
    }

    dataReader = async () => {
        const fatherData = JSON.parse((await AsyncStorage.getItem('@fatherdata')));
        await this.setState({ father: fatherData });
    }

    setData = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@Student', JSON.stringify(this.state.studentData));
        this.state.studentData = 'Holiwis'
        console.log(this.state.studentData);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={style.containerF}>
                    <Text>DATOS DEL PADRE:</Text>
                    <Text>Id: {this.state.father.id}</Text>
                    <Text>Nombre: {this.state.father.name}</Text>
                    <Text>Email: {this.state.father.email}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

function Student({ route }) {

   const student = route.params;  

    return (

        <View>
           
            <View style={style.containerF}>
                <Parent />
            </View>
            <View style={style.container}>
                <Text>DATOS DEL ESTUDIANTE:</Text>
                <Text>Id: {student.id}</Text>
                <Text>Nombre: {student.displayName}</Text>
                <Text>Código: {student.personalCode}</Text>
                <Text>Nivel: {student.level}</Text>
                <Text>Grado: {student.grade}</Text>
                <Text>Sección: {student.section}</Text>
                <Text>Carrera: {student.career}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default Student;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <View style={style.containerF}>
                <Parent student={student}/>
            </View>
```

Y en el componente Parent lo recuperas con this.props.student